# Trying to Rotate the North Pole View of a Globe

Tags: geographics

My goal is to generate diagrams like this.
[image]

But I would like to be able to rotate the globe about the North Pole, so that I can represent different times of the day.

When I use ImageRotate, the results are a little weird.
[image]

That little black spot on the lower left is what was the original black background.

It seems like I'm doing things the hard way again.  I hope there is a better way, but is there a better way to rotate this globe?

---

Too late now, but here's the code for the original (without the point).

```
Show[Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{-1.1, -1.1}, {6, 1.1}], White, Thickness[0.01], Arrowheads[0.04], Table[Arrow[{{6, y}, {1.1, y}}], {y, -1, 1, 0.5}]}], Graphics @@ GeoGraphics[GeoProjection -> "Orthographic", GeoCenter -> {90, 0}, GeoRange -> "World", GeoGridLines -> Automatic, Background -> None], ImageSize -> 800]
```

Comment: Please post the code in the image as text. It makes it easier for us to test it out on our own.

Comment: I'll do that next time. The code pastes in such an ugly way that I thought this would be preferred.

Comment: `InputForm` is always appreciated, so people do not have to retype what you already typed. It can often be edited to look better anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** It turns out oblique `"Orthographic"` projection (mentioned in [the link provided by J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118095)) has been implemented. Using the option `"Centering" -> {90, - 30}` gives the desired rotation in OP's case without the need for `ImageRotate`:

```
Row[GeoGraphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[fresno]}, ImageSize -> 300, 
    GeoRange -> "World", GeoGridLines -> Automatic, 
    GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"], 
    GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", "Centering" -> {90, #}}] & /@ 
 {-30, -60, 45}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
fresno = Entity["City", {"Fresno", "California", "UnitedStates"}];

geog1 = GeoGraphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[fresno]}, 
   ImageSize -> 400, GeoRange -> "World", GeoGridLines -> Automatic, 
   GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"], 
   GeoCenter -> {90, 0}, GeoProjection -> "Orthographic"];
```

You can use `ImageRotate` with  [`GeoStylingImageFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoStylingImageFunction.html) as follows and post-process to rotate the `Point` primitive:

```
geog2 = GeoGraphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[fresno]}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, GeoRange -> "World", GeoGridLines -> Automatic, 
    GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels", 
     GeoStylingImageFunction -> (ImageRotate[#, 30 Degree, ImageDimensions@#] &)], 
    GeoCenter -> {90, 0}, GeoProjection -> "Orthographic"] /. 
   Point[x_] :> GeometricTransformation[Point[x], RotationTransform[30 Degree]];
```

An easier approach is to rotate `Rasterize`d `geog1`:

```
raster = Rasterize[geog1, Background -> None];
geog3 = Show[ImageRotate[raster, 30 Degree, ImageDimensions @ raster, 
    Background -> None], ImageSize -> 300]

Row[{geog1, geog2, geog3}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
rotate = ImageRotate[raster, #, ImageDimensions @ raster, Background -> None] &;

arrows = Graphics[{Arrowheads[.15], AbsoluteThickness[7], White, 
    Arrow[{Scaled[{2, #}], Scaled[{1, #}]}] & /@ (Range[4 ] / 5)}];

frames = Show[rotate[# Degree], arrows, Background -> Black, 
     PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 700] & /@ Range[0, 360, 10];

Export["rotategeog.gif", frames]
```

[image]

Comment: The GridLines will be off in this case, right? They won't follow the lat/long lines correctly, because only the background has rotated.

Comment: @CarlLange, you are right. Not sure if OP wants to rotate the gridlines too.

Comment: @Carl and kglr, Jose mentions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118095) that `GeoGraphics[]` will support more oblique projections at some point, tho I am not sure if it's been done for at least the orthographic projection.

Comment: Indeed, I came across that as well, but it doesn't appear to be in 12.2 for more than `ObliqueMercator` at least, which doesn't work with this range.

Comment: Thank you @J.M. for the link. It turns out the option `"Centering"` works as described by Jose  for `"Orthographic"` projection too.

Comment: It does!? The syntax here is a bit surprising to me - in the docs it suggests `"Centering" -> {{lat, lon}, az}`, but it doesn't look like that's what you're using here? Anyway, that's definitely the more correct way to do it, and it certainly does work! That should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Well, that's nice to see! I don't recall if this is documented tho... (and my more unreasonable wish is that there really should be documentation for all the supported projections)

Comment: (If we're adding unreasonable wishes, I deeply want EPSG ID support for projections)

Answer (score 9):

[kglr's updated answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/239295/57593) is the more correct option. My less correct answer follows.

There are two tricks here - one to be able to get the same image size regardless of background in the GeoGraphics, and another to use ImageCompose to place one image inside another.

Here we have a function to give back an image of the same size given any rotation. There's a bit of a hack here to make the background of the `GeoGraphics` *and* the background of the `ImageRotate` `Purple`. Unfortunately when you use ImageRotate on a GeoGraphics, it appears to disregard the alpha channel and cast the background to white (even if you had it set to `None` or `Transparent`). We then replace all `Purple` with `Transparent`, to get a nice image we can compose with. You also use `ImageCrop` to get a consistent image size.

```
rotateGlobe[d_] := 
 ColorReplace[
  ImageCrop@
   ImageRotate[
    GeoGraphics[GeoRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, 
     GeoBackground -> "Coastlines", GeoProjection -> "Orthographic", 
     GeoRange -> "World", GeoGridLines -> Automatic, 
     GeoCenter -> {90, 0}, Background -> Purple, ImageSize -> 400], d,
     Background -> Purple], Purple -> Transparent]
```

We'll also define your "arrows" to make it more clear what we're doing.

```
arrows = Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{-1.1, -1.1}, {6, 1.1}], White, 
   Thickness[0.01], Arrowheads[0.04], 
   Table[Arrow[{{6, y}, {1.1, y}}], {y, -1, 1, 0.5}]}]
```

And now we can animate the two together. `ImageCompose` here is your friend, as you have two images with quite different dimensions. I used `Scaled` a lot, eyeballing scale and position until it looked right.

```
Animate[
 ImageCompose[arrows, ImageResize[rotateGlobe[d], Scaled[.25]], 
  Scaled[{.18, .5}]],
 {d, -\[Pi], \[Pi], .1}]
```

or,

```
Table[
 ImageCompose[arrows, ImageResize[rotateGlobe[d], Scaled[.25]], 
  Scaled[{.18, .5}]],
 {d, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is very messy code, if someone would like to take the basic idea (use `ImageCompose` instead of `Show`) and create a better answer, please feel free.